# How can I split comma separated words wrapped in quotes efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I've done some basic string parsing in python with split, and I currently have this type of output:

```
{"repositories":["docker1","myImage","repo123"]}
```

The "repositories" is guaranteed but the list may go on for hundreds.  My first thought is to start at [17:-2] which would leave a comma separated list of quoted words, then split into a list by the commas, and then take each of those words [1:-1].

Is there a more 'elegant' solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like JSON! Assuming it is...

```
>>> import json
>>> a = json.loads('{"repositories":["docker1","myImage","repo123"]}')
>>> a['repositories']
["docker1","myImage","repo123"]  # A python list, not a string
```

If it *is* guaranteed to be JSON, you can use the above method to convert the string directly into a Python object, obviating the need for any parsing.

Comment: Didn't even occur to me it was JSON.  I've always seen the word in various programming contexts but never knew what it actually was.  But the code you provided set me up for exactly what I needed.  Thanks!